# Comparing resource use of different methods

Tags: java, android, performance, optimization, measure

I often doubt between two or more forms of doing something. In Android, I try to do it the way more efficent, the way in which the processor uses less resources and RAM. 
How I can measure the cpu and RAM consumption of an application in order to compare different methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could profile your application. The Android SDK comes with traceview and the [instructions](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) are pretty good. You could also watch memory allocations from [DDMS](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/07/using-ddms-to-profile-android-apps/).